# Atomically open and lock file

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a file `foo.hex` that is accessed by two processes. One process has `O_RDONLY` access and the other has `O_RDWR` access.

When starting the system for the very first time, the reading process should not access the file before the writing process has initialized it.

Thus, I wrote something like this to initialize the file.

```
fd = open("foo.hex", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
flock(fd, LOCK_EX);

init_structures(fd);

flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
```

Which still leaves the possibility to the reader process to access the file before it is initialized.

I couldn't find a way to `open()` and `flock()` in an atomic fashion. Besides mutexes what other possibilities are there to achieve my goal in an elegant way with as little overhead as possible (since it's only used once, the very first time the system is started)?

Comment: This isn't your actual problem, but you might want to be using `open("foo.hex", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666)` in the writer.

Comment: @zwol right, I actually open it with O_CREAT, 0666 but that doesn't change the problem with the race condition.

Comment: Remember: `flock()` locking is advisory, not mandatory, so even after you've applied the lock in one process, the other process can go ahead and do what it will if it ignores the lock.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for this hint, that's actually where I screwed up on the reader side. Initially I thought I only have to protect the file during creation/initialisation but I will now implement a more general solution based on John's approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the writer create a file called "foo.hex.init" instead, and initialize that before renaming it to "foo.hex".  This way, the reader can never see the uninitialized file contents.

Comment: I was considering that, but wasn't sure if this is how it's done or if it's more a hack.

Comment: This is how it's done.  Renaming files to protect them while writing is super common.  Web browsers do it while downloading files to make sure you don't try to open half of a file, for example.  File locking is fraught with peril, and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: About renaming.  Assume "foo.hex" exists before programs start, and the writer makes "foo.hex.init".  To rename, does not "foo.hex" need to be deleted (or renamed to "some_tmp_name") before  "foo.hex.init" is renamed to  "foo.hex"?  If this is so, does that leave a window where no "foo.hex" exists - which may cause trouble for the reader?

Comment: @chux On a POSIX-compliant system, `rename("foo.hex.init", "foo.hex") ` is required to atomically replace `foo.hex` -- there will be no point at which `foo.hex` can be observed not to exist or to have the wrong contents.  However, on Windows, the old file must be deleted first, and there is indeed an unavoidable race window where `foo.hex` can be observed not to exist.  If I was writing a program where this mattered, I would simply have the reader spin a few times before giving up.

Comment: Code that requires the atomic replacement logic, typically uses the POSIX [`link()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) (rather than `rename()`).

Comment: @NominalAnimal `link()` can't be used on directories, though. And are you sure POSIX `rename()` isn't atomic?  The POSIX standard states *If the link named by the `new` argument exists, it shall be removed and `old` renamed to `new`. In this case, a link named `new` shall remain visible to other threads throughout the renaming operation and refer either to the file referred to by `new` or `old` before the operation began.* with the added benefit of *If the `rename()` function fails for any reason other than `EIO`, any file named by `new` shall be unaffected.*

Comment: @AndrewHenle: No, I didn't mean to imply [`rename()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) is not atomic on POSIXy systems; just that you usually see code using `link()` (rather than `rename()`). There are both historical and use-case reasons. The main use case reason is that `link()` does not rename the new file, it only makes the old file name refer to the inode of the new file. The historical use case is related to NFS file locking (not relying on NLM, i.e. `fcntl()` record locks) and creating lockfiles; see e.g. [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/251004/).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be to remove the existing file, recreate it without permissions for any process to access it, then change the file permissions after it's written:

```
unlink("foo.hex");
fd = open("foo.hex", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0);

init_structures(fd);

fchmod(fd, 0666);
```

That likely won't work if you're running as root.  (Which you shouldn't be doing anyway...)

This would prevent any process from using old data once the `unlink()` call is made.  Depending on your requirements, that may or may not be worth the extra reader code necessary to deal with the file not existing or being accessible while the new file is being initialized.

Personally, I'd use the `rename( "foo.hex.init", "foo.hex" )` solution unless `init_structures()` takes *significant* time, and there's a real, hard requirement to not use old data once new data is available.  But sometimes important people aren't comfortable with using old data while any portion of new data is available, and they don't really understand, "If the reader process started two milliseconds earlier it would use the old data anyway".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is for the reader process to sleep a little and retry upon finding that the file doesn't yet exist, or is empty.

```
int open_for_read(const char *fname)
{
    int retries = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1) {
            if (errno != ENOENT) return -1;
            goto retry;
        } 
        if (flock(fd, LOCK_SH)) {
            close(fd);
            return -1;
        }

        struct stat st;
        if (fstat(fd, &st)) {
            close(fd);
            return -1;
        }
        if (st.st_size == 0) {
            close(fd);
            goto retry;
        }
        return fd;

    retry:
        if (++retries > MAX_RETRIES) return -1;
        sleep(1);
    }
    /* not reached */
}
```

You need similar code on the write side, so that if the writer loses the race it doesn't have to be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of [inter-process communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Perhaps use a named semaphore that the writing process locks before opening and initializing the file? Then the reading process could attempt to lock the semaphore as well, and if it succeeds and the file doesn't exist it unlocks the semaphore and wait a little while and retry.

The simplest way though, especially if the file will be recreated by the writing process every time, is already in [the answer by John Zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46074258/440558).